# how do I drive the width of span class with variable

Tags: javascript, html

Please where am I mistaking?
I am trying to change the progress bar base on variable and it is not working.

```
    <script>
        function grafWidth(GtempPar) {
         var GtempPar = 30;
          
        document.getElementById('progress-in').style.width = GtempPar + "px";
        }
    </script>

    <div class="progress">
        <a class="majko">Temp_G_back</a>
        <span class="progress-val"><div id="Gtemp"></div>°C</span>
        <span class="progress-bar"><span class="progress-in".style.width =" 80px"></span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: There's no element with id of "progress-in" in the markup. Notice also gavgrif's answer.

Comment: You are also not calling the function anywhere.

Comment: Side note: Your inline style in the html is not correct syntax

Comment: Pay also attention to where you are calling the function as it needs to be called after the html elements, you are selecting, initialize. Just pasting @charlietfl's code into your script tag will result in an error. Better to insert it after the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the span is an inline element and as such you can't specify a width (or margins / padding / height etc). In order to apply the styling try - making the span display y: inline-block and you should be able to apply width changes as expected.

Also the span has an id not a class and you have to call the function with an argument that you are wanting the pass into the function. and the var inside the function is redundant.

```js
function grafWidth(GtempPar) {
   document.getElementById('progress-in').style.width = GtempPar + "px";
}
        
        
grafWidth(150); // this calls the function and passes 150 in to set the width of the progress bar to 150px (out of 200)
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

.progress-bar  {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 32px
}

#progress-in {
  background: red;
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
    <a class="majko">Temp_G_back</a>
    <span class="progress-val"><div id="Gtemp"></div>°C</span>
    <span class="progress-bar"><span id="progress-in"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear all. Thank you, i changed it as described but it is not working. See>

Comment: <div class="progress">
            <a class="majko">Temp_G_back</a>
            <span class="progress-val"><div id="Gtemp"></div>°C</span>
            <span class="progress-bar"><span id="progress-in"></span></span>
        </div>

        <script>
            function grafWidth(GtempPar) {
                document.getElementById('progress-in').style.width = GtempPar + "px";
            }


            grafWidth(150); // this calls the function and passes 150 in to set the width of the progress bar to 150px (out of 200)
        </script>

Comment: You will need to use the CSS that I put in as well - ... dont worry about what you already  have = jsut take the code from the snippet directly - all parts of it - html / js / css and see if that works. It works in the snippet and so will work for tyou - then you can work out how to modify yoyr existing code to match what I did. - do'n t get disheartend - the best approach to learning is to trry doing it and seeing what works. Also look at the console and see if you have any errors

Comment: Thank you. It seems like I have some other errors in CSS but wthen I removed it a pasted yours it works fine. Thank you once again!

Comment: you are welcome - its always exciting when you can see something work. Always keep learning and trying new things and the console is your friend for spotting  errors :) happy coding :)